# When is NSEnumerator finished?

Tags: cocoa, nsenumerator

How do we know when enumeration is finished?  The docs say: the return value of

```
nextObject
```

is nil when all objects have been enumerated.  I was hoping to implement some "delegate-like" behavior whereby ...

```
if (nextObject == nil) { 
    do something because we're done!
}
```

But I see there is no such thing as:

```
enumerationDidFinish:
```

where in the following block could I check for the enumerator to be complete?

```
NSArray *anArray = // ... ;
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [anArray objectEnumerator];
id object;

while ((object = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    // do something with object...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `while` loop finishes, you know the enumeration is complete. You could call the delegate method then.

Comment: yep... just a basic thing I was forgetting.  This is what happens when you just use cocoa calls nonstop and forget the basics of looping!

Comment: More specifically, Edward has it right - while assigning the -nextObject to `object`, the while loop is evaluating, essentially "while there's a next object, do the following:".

Answer (score 2):

Just put your code after the whole `while` block.

Then when the enumeration is done, it will execute, and you will know it has reached the end.

Answer (score 2):

The enumerator finishes when the value returned from `nextObject` is `nil`

Answer (score 2):

How about immediatley after the while() loop. When nextObject returns nil, the enumeration is complete and the loop condition fails, continuing execution immediately after the loop
body.

Answer (score 0):

Since if the returned "object" is nil, the while loop won't continue execution in the body, it will break to the end of the loop, putting whatever you want to do with your object there would be a good idea.